# Software for getting Back Up of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS along with newly installed software

Tags: 14.04, software-center, backup

I have **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** . After installing this OS , many **new softwares** are installed , and also many packages are updated.

Now, my question is , is there any **software** ,with the help of which I can get **full back up** with the **newly installed software**,  and also , while I installed this OS with the **Back Up CD/DVD** in another Computer , I will get all the previously installed software in the **new computer**.

If, there is such , please share with me.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please remember to mark it as the correct answer by clicking on the grey tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org) to backup the whole system in its current state.
[Download the ISO](http://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=stable) and create a bootable media (CD/DVD/USB) from it.

Boot from the media and save the whole disk or single partitions to another disk.
If you want to restore the image - boot from the media again and start restoring.

Comprehensive information on how to exactly do this and the download location : [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)

Comment: After install the **Clonezilla** , while I getting **backup** and **restoring** , is internet needed ?

Comment: I am not a big fan of clonezilla. I sugget you only need to back up data in home and any system files you manually edit. This leads to much smaller backups.With clonezilla you need to also back up your partition table and the backup images are huge.

Comment: The default tool - https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/deja-dup/

Comment: @Bapi : Installing is a wrong expression ... I assume you meant : After creating the media ... and no - there is no internet connection necessary when you backup and restore to another disk. :)

Comment: @ cl-netbox : ok, thnks

Answer (score 0):

There are many applications that will help complete this task effectively.

**GParted** will shrink the partitions of a hard disk. Then an application can be used for backup, such as.

**Clonezilla Live CD/USB**, will backup to local media / samba / ssh but internet is only required if you intend to back or restore from a remote machine ie: SSH or SAMBA.

[G4l](http://sourceforge.net/projects/g4l/)   **G4L** is a hard disk and partition imaging and cloning tool. The created images are optionally compressed and transferred to an FTP server or cloned locally. CIFS(Windows), SSHFS and NFS support included, and udpcast and fsarchiver options

Remastersys
with [Remastersys](https://launchpad.net/%7Emutse-young/+archive/ubuntu/remastersys/+packages) you could do the following.

```
sudo mkdir -vp /opt/remastersys

cd /opt/remastersys

sudo wget https://launchpad.net/~mutse-young/+archive/ubuntu/remastersys/+files/remastersys_3.0.5-1%7Etrusty1_all.deb
sudo wget https://launchpad.net/~mutse-young/+archive/ubuntu/remastersys/+files/remastersys-gtk_3.0.5-1%7Etrusty1_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb # will finish with dependency issues

echo y | sudo apt-get install -f # this will fix the dependency issues

sudo remastersys backup
```

Look in

> /home/remastersys/remastersys/custom-backup.iso

This custom iso can be used to create a custom USB or CD.